# php sql pagination syntax error

Tags: php, sql, pagination

i have a pagination code but i have syntax errors i think, but i could no solve it.

```
<?php  
$sql = "SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM inventario";
$rs_result = mysqli_query($sql);  
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs_result);  
$total_records = $row[0];  
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);  
$pagLink = "<ul class=\"pagination pull-right\">";

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  
         $pagLink .= “<li><a href=\"lista.php?page=”.$i.“\">”.$i.“</a></li>”;  
};  
echo $pagLink . “</ul>”;  
?>
```

what seems to be the problema?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include the syntax errors you're getting

Comment: **Don't say "I got an error". Always say "Here is the error I got" and then show us the exact error.** Don't paraphrase it. Don't retype it. Cut & paste the error message exactly from your screen.

Comment: It might be an issue with the code you've added here, but you seem to have an odd mix of quotes - look at the syntax highlighting above. Compare the highlighting on the first line with the highlighting in the line inside your for loop - you've using odd quotes in the latter line, which I suspect is what's breaking your code. You need to use `"`

Comment: You have curly quotes `“ ”`; change them to regular quotes. That alone will break your code.

Comment: remove outer double qoutes(") to single qoutes(')

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the docs for the procedural call to [mysqli_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php),  the first argument must be a resource link from a previous successful call to mysqli_connect().

Answer (score 0):

It may make things easier if you use single and double quotes, rather than escaping double quotes within strings. The bug in your code was on the 4th to last line:

```
<?php  
$sql = "SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM inventario";
$rs_result = mysqli_query( $sql );  
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs_result);  
$total_records = $row[0];  
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);  
$pagLink = '<ul class="pagination pull-right">';

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  
  $pagLink .= '<li><a href="lista.php?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';  
};  

echo $pagLink . '</ul>';
```

Comment: *"It may make things easier if you use single and double quotes"* - Somewhat true. But the OP's code contains curly/smart quotes.  `“ ”` which is most likely the/a reason why it's failing.